# launch Fragment activity in another activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to pass a view from one fragment activity to another activity. I am a newbie at Fragments and am not sure if this is possible.

Any thoughts are gladly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Anyone please? any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to do this, the view will be tied to the activity.

Why do you want to do this, or more specifically what is it you want to achieve?

You can pass information from one activity to another via Intent Extras if you need to recreate the view based on information.

Comment: Thanks, I believe thats the answer I was looking for!!